# How to access textview inside nested layout

Tags: android

I have being struggling with this the whole day, I wish to access a `textview` inside a `linear layout` which is inturn inside a `relative layout`.

I have used this code in my mainactivity.java,

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment { 
    public PlaceholderFragment() {} 
    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false); 
        forgot= (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordText); 
        String s=(String) forgot.getText(); 
        forgot.setText("hello"); 
        return rootView;
    } 
}
```

please help.

Comment: post your layout xml.

Comment: That should work, findViewById does a search through all child views.  Are you sure that the id you're using is in the content view you set?  And if you're in something which is inflated separately (like a dialog) are you using findViewById on the correct element?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Are you sure `forgotPasswordText` is in the layout inflated in `rootView`?

Comment: My textview is in a file named fragment_main.xml... I also have a textview outside the linear layout, and for that text view the above command works prorperly

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
forgot= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordText);
```

Comment: public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

  public PlaceholderFragment() {
  } 

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,
     container, false);
  
   forgot= (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordText);
       String s=(String) forgot.getText();
   forgot.setText("hello");
   
   return rootView;
  }
 }

Comment: thats my code, it gives m an error Description 
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ActivityMain.PlaceholderFragment

Comment: @user3719250 Updated code after seeing your posted code, try this

Comment: See if the textview is inside the fragment xml then use 
`forgot= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordText)`
else use
`forgot= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordText)`

Answer (score 1):

```
forgot = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordText);
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does, where it would go, and why you chose this approach.   Code only answers are not high quality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a TextView from your Layout the only thing you have to do is this:

```
TextView forgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordText);
```

In android you give the ID to a View and you can acess the View with the ID without knowing parent-Views or something. Hope this helped.

Comment: My textview is in a file named fragment_main.xml... I also have a textview outside the linear layout, and for that text view the above command works prorperly

Comment: Maybe you could post your Layout.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine. just use this -- 
TextView forgot= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2); as said by @AndroidWarrior. I tested your code with this change and it works.